# Receiving data in chunks stops fetching before all data is received

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I have a node application running on a Heroku server. On a specific route, its sending data in chunks.

This works well locally, it works after deploy to Heroku (when I visit the url directly in the browser) and it works when I sent a request using postman.

But when I want to fetch this data in React, it acts differently. I do receive data in chunks dynamically as supposed, but it suddenly stops.

I have an example, that returns 2505 objects in an array - which it does correctly - every time - using postman.
But using javascript, I receive between 600-1800 objects and then it stops fetching. Returns with a 200 and no errors - and my heroku says status 200 too!

Here is the function in React

```js
import { parse } from "partial-json";
... 

const [matches, setMatches] = useState(null);
...

const getFeed = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(endpoint);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
      }

      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      let partialResult = "";

      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();

        if (done) {
          break;
        }

        partialResult += new TextDecoder().decode(value);

        if (partialResult.startsWith("[") && partialResult.endsWith("]")) {
          const result = parse(partialResult);

          setMatches((prevResults) => {
            if (!prevResults) {
              return result.sort((a, b) => Number(a.price) - Number(b.price));
            }

            const mergedArray = [...(prevResults || []), ...(result || [])];
            const uniqueResults = Array.from(
              new Set(mergedArray.map((item) => beautifyURL(item.title)))
            )
              .map((productId) =>
                mergedArray.find(
                  (item) => beautifyURL(item.title) === productId
                )
              )
              .sort((a, b) => Number(a.price) - Number(b.price));

            return uniqueResults;
          });
          partialResult = ""; // Reset for the next chunk
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

So it is not completely broken since I do receive data and get status 200. But why does it stop? And I assume it is a frontend issue, since it works with postman and going straight to the url in the browser?

Comment: `getFeed` is only called once and there are no other fetches in your code so how are you receiving chunks of information? [Server-sent events](https://jvns.ca/blog/2021/01/12/day-36--server-sent-events-are-cool--and-a-fun-bug/) might be a better approach for your needs and are easy to set up.

Comment: Yes I only call it once on first render. Server-sent events sadly didn't make any different.